# How to save all "self" variables in Python after __init__()

Tags: python, oop, self

I have a class and some self variables inside `__init__()` function. Some of the self variables are derived and it has mixed data types. How can I save all these self variables so I can debug it whenever errors occur?

Please advise

Comment: What do you mean by "self variables"? Do you mean attributes like `self.foo` or `self.bar`, or do you mean other parameters that `__init__()` takes? Please show an example of what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save data to an external source, like a file?

Comment: @wjandrea : I want to save all the variables initialized on __init__ in one file but I think it is impossible since all the variables could have different types.

Comment: @David : I want to save all the variables initialized on __init__ in one file but I think it is impossible since all the variables could have different types.

Comment: @chandrasutrisno: You can see pickle: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: @David : How can I save all the self variables in one pickle file then?

Comment: @chandrasutrisno I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out pickle: [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). It works with all data types, even with custom ones (but you still have to have the custom classes defined when you load the data)
It saves data to one single file. If you know what variables you want to save you can use:

```
import pickle


class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        pickle.dump([a, b, c], open('dumpfile.pickle', 'wb'))


test = Test(1, 2, 3)  # Creates file dumpfile.pickle that contains the pickled list [1, 2, 3]
# To load the data back, even if in another file:
loaded_data = pickle.load(open('dumpfile.pickle', 'rb'))  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this. Will give it a try.